# Loop and List logic

Tags: c#, wpf, list, xaml, loops

I have a program that upon loading the user control, adds graphics to a map layer (You shouldn't have to know much about map stuff to help, I believe the problem is with my loop logic.)

Here is my code:

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();

    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=USSW7DEVWS16\\DEVELOPER;Initial Catalog=acrGIS;Integrated Security=True";

    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM arcObjects", con))
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int ID = reader.GetInt32(0);
            Object = reader.GetString(1);
            OComment = reader.GetString(2);
            OStreet = reader.GetString(3);
            OCity = reader.GetString(4);
            OState = reader.GetString(5);
            OZip = reader.GetString(6);
            OSpec = reader.GetString(7);

            arcObjects.Add(new arcObject() { Object_Num = Object, Comments = OComment, Street = OStreet, City = OCity, State = OState, Zip = OZip, Spec = OSpec });
        }

        con.Close();
        foreach (arcObject objects in arcObjects)
        {
            Locator InitialLocatorTask = new Locator("http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Locators/TA_Streets_US_10/GeocodeServer");
            InitialLocatorTask.AddressToLocationsCompleted += InitialLocatorTask_AddressToLocatonCompleted;
            InitialLocatorTask.Failed += InitialLocatorTask_Failed;
            AddressToLocationsParameters addressParams = new AddressToLocationsParameters();

            Dictionary<string, string> address = addressParams.Address;

            address.Add("Street", objects.Street);
            address.Add("City", objects.City);
            address.Add("State", objects.State);
            address.Add("Zip", objects.Zip);

            InitialLocatorTask.AddressToLocationsAsync(addressParams);
        }
    }
}

private void InitialLocatorTask_AddressToLocatonCompleted(object sender, ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.AddressToLocationsEventArgs args)
{
    con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();

    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=USSW7DEVWS16\\DEVELOPER;Initial Catalog=acrGIS;Integrated Security=True";

    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM arcObjects", con))
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int ID = reader.GetInt32(0);
            Object = reader.GetString(1);
            OComment = reader.GetString(2);
            OStreet = reader.GetString(3);
            OCity = reader.GetString(4);
            OState = reader.GetString(5);
            OZip = reader.GetString(6);
            OSpec = reader.GetString(7);

            CandidateListBox.Items.Clear();

            List<AddressCandidate> returnedCandidates = args.Results;

            foreach (AddressCandidate candidate in returnedCandidates)
            {
                if (candidate.Score >= 80)
                {
                    CandidateListBox.Items.Add(candidate.Address);

                    if (OSpec == "Meter")
                    {
                        Graphic graphic = new Graphic()
                        {
                            Symbol = AddressLayout.Resources["WaterMeterRenderer"] as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.Symbol,
                            Geometry = candidate.Location
                        };

                        string address2 = OCity + ", " + OState + " " + OZip;

                        graphic.Attributes.Add("MeterNum", Object);
                        graphic.Attributes.Add("Comment", OComment);
                        graphic.Attributes.Add("Address1", OStreet);
                        graphic.Attributes.Add("Address2", address2);

                        if (candidate.Location.SpatialReference == null)
                        {
                            candidate.Location.SpatialReference = new SpatialReference(4326);
                        }

                        // if (!candidate.Location.SpatialReference.Equals(MyMap.SpatialReference))
                        //{
                        // if (MyMap.SpatialReference.Equals(new SpatialReference(102100)) && candidate.Location.SpatialReference.Equals(new SpatialReference(4326)))
                        // graphic.Geometry = _mercator.FromGeographic(graphic.Geometry);
                        // else if (MyMap.SpatialReference.Equals(new SpatialReference(4326)) && candidate.Location.SpatialReference.Equals(new SpatialReference(102100)))
                        // graphic.Geometry = _mercator.ToGeographic(graphic.Geometry);
                        // else if (MyMap.SpatialReference != new SpatialReference(4326))
                        // {
                        GeometryService geometryService = new  
GeometryService("http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

                        geometryService.ProjectCompleted += (s, a) =>
                        {
                            graphic.Geometry = a.Results[0].Geometry;
                        };

                        geometryService.Failed += (s, a) =>
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Projection error: " + a.Error.Message);
                        };

                        //geometryService.ProjectAsync(new List<Graphic> { graphic }, MyMap.SpatialReference);
                        //    }
                        //}

                        FeatureLayer graphicsLayer = MyMap.Layers["WaterMeterLayer"] as FeatureLayer;
                        graphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(graphic);
                        //return;
                    }

                    if (OSpec == "Lot")
                    {
                        Graphic graphic = new Graphic()
                        {
                            Symbol = AddressLayout.Resources["LotRenderer"] as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.Symbol,
                            Geometry = candidate.Location
                        };

                        string address2 = OCity + ", " + OState + " " + OZip;

                        graphic.Attributes.Add("MeterNum", Object);
                        graphic.Attributes.Add("Comment", OComment);
                        graphic.Attributes.Add("Address1", OStreet);
                        graphic.Attributes.Add("Address2", address2);

                        if (candidate.Location.SpatialReference == null)
                        {
                            candidate.Location.SpatialReference = new SpatialReference(4326);
                        }

                        //if (!candidate.Location.SpatialReference.Equals(MyMap.SpatialReference))
                        // {
                        // if (MyMap.SpatialReference.Equals(new SpatialReference(102100)) && candidate.Location.SpatialReference.Equals(new SpatialReference(4326)))
                        // graphic.Geometry = _mercator.FromGeographic(graphic.Geometry);
                        // else if (MyMap.SpatialReference.Equals(new SpatialReference(4326)) && candidate.Location.SpatialReference.Equals(new SpatialReference(102100)))
                        // graphic.Geometry = _mercator.ToGeographic(graphic.Geometry);
                        //    else if (MyMap.SpatialReference != new SpatialReference(4326))
                        //    {
                        GeometryService geometryService = new GeometryService("http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

                         geometryService.ProjectCompleted += (s, a) =>
                         {
                             graphic.Geometry = a.Results[0].Geometry;
                         };

                         geometryService.Failed += (s, a) =>
                         {
                             MessageBox.Show("Projection error: " + a.Error.Message);
                         };

                         //geometryService.ProjectAsync(new List<Graphic> { graphic }, MyMap.SpatialReference);
                         // }
                         // }

                         FeatureLayer graphicsLayer = MyMap.Layers["LotLayer"] as FeatureLayer;
                         graphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(graphic);
                         // return;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     con.Close();
 }


public void InitialLocatorTask_Failed(object sender, TaskFailedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Locator service failed: " + e.Error);
}
```

I know what it happening, the foreach loop in the UserControl_Loaded is adding things to the dictionary and then the while loop in the InitailTaskToAddress_Completed runs over and over again (9 times to be exact). What the problem is, is though while all of the graphics are being placed in the correct place, the attributes of those graphics are all the same...

For some reason it is not getting them. If you want me to clear anything up, just let me know. Also, if you would like to see my XAML, I can also show you that. I am using C# and WPF, as well as arcGIS. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here - you loop over all the rows in the data set in your Loaded event, then for each row you loop over the rows again in the Completed handler - do you want the completed handler to process the row that it was initiated against?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through and seeing where the code first starts to behave weird?

Comment: Yes I have tried stepping through it... And it works like it should, but does not stop after it goes through all of the objects in the list.

Comment: Why is `SELECT * FROM arcObjects` done twice? Once in Loaded and once in completed? In `InitialLocatorTask_AddressToLocatonCompleted` (typo here, should be Location) shouldn't you just use the data you just got before? You seem to be assigning the `AddressCandidate` many times with the same data. Is that by design?

Comment: I redid the SELECT statement so I could use that information again. I was doing a foreach loop with the List but the same results were happening and yes that is by design. It there a way in C# to access a list by one element at a time?